# Proving that $$ [\phi(\vec{x}, 0), \phi(\vec{x}, t)] \sim e^{-i m t}-e^{+i m t} $$ in QFT

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, commutator, complex-numbers, analyticity

So far, I get the following (for the left term in the integral, $d$=3):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} \Delta_{+}(x) &= \int \frac{\mathrm{d} \vec{p}^{d}}{(2 \pi)^{d} 2 e(\vec{p})} \exp (-i t e(\vec{p})) \\ &=\frac{ \operatorname{Vol}\left(S^{d-1}\right)}{2(2 \pi)^{d}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d} p p^{d-1}}{\sqrt{p^{2}+m^{2}}} \exp (-i t \sqrt{p^{2}+m^{2}}) \\ &=\frac{ \operatorname{Vol}\left(S^{d-1}\right)}{2(2 \pi)^{d}} \int_{m}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} e\left(e^{2}-m^{2}\right)^{(d-2) / 2} \exp (-i t e) \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and according to my class notes, the last term goes like ~$e^{-imt}/i$ for $t \rightarrow \pm \infty$, but I am stuck in proving it. I have tried integrating by parts and applying Cauchy's residue theorem but with no luck.